# uploading using form-data a remote file

Tags: node.js, form-data, node-fetch

in my node application I want to use FormData to upload a remote image.
To do this I'm trying the following

```
  const form = new FormData();
  ...
  const result = await fetch(image);
  form.append("file", result.body);
  ...
```

This is generating the following error:

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
```

I'm wondering what I have to pass to `form.append` to make it work. I tried also using `result.blob()` without any luck. Any help appreciated.